# c# grpc take 100 record each stream

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, grpc-c#

I have 4 stream: A, B, C, D

Now my code use ReadAllAsync() to process each stream, it's running good with less data. But when I have 1 million row data to read. It will be bad practice.

I want to change to: Read each 100 record from A, then B, C, D (they need data of A first)

All A, B, C, D is child of A, B, C, D abstract class BaseStream and running parallel

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What's the issue you're facing?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I don't know how to take just 100 record then skip to process again.
All 4 stream running in while loop

Comment: `while (true) { foreach (var stream in streams) { for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { var record = readRecord(stream); } } }` ? Perhaps with some check to skip to the next stream (break out of the innermost loop) if there's no more records at the moment.